How can I calculate the RDF using only part of the trajectory in MDAnalysis?
I have a very long MD trajectory, and I would like to perform different analyses using only specific parts of the trajectory, for example: from frame 100 to 1000.
Mainly. I need to calculate the RDF. I already calculated the "normal RDF", meaning along the whole simulation. However, I would like to perform the same calculation, but only using a specific number of frames. Is there a way to do this? Should I calculate the RDF manually by calculating the distance at each step?
I have tried to do this:
frame_count = len(all_p.trajectory)

half_frame_count = int(frame_count/2)
frames_first_half = []
frames_second_half = []

for ts in all_p.trajectory[:half_frame_count]:
    frames_first_half.append(ts.positions.copy())
for ts in all_p.trajectory[half_frame_count:]:
    frames_second_half.append(ts.positions.copy())

u_fragment_1 = mda.Universe(PDB, coordinates=frames_first_half)
A_1 = u_fragment_1.select_atoms('*selection A*') 
B_1 = u_fragment_1.select_atoms('*selection B*') 

u_fragment_2 = mda.Universe(PDB, coordinates=frames_second_half)
A_2 = u_fragment_2.select_atoms('*selection A*') 
B_2 = u_fragment_2.select_atoms('*selection B*') 

and then performing the RDFs
irdf = rdf.InterRDF(CA_A_1, CA_B_1,
                    nbins=2000,
                    range=(0.0,100.0),
                    exclusion_block=(1,1),
                    )
irdf.run()

rdf_x_axis = irdf.results.bins
rdf_y_axis = irdf.results.rdf
plt.plot(rdf_x_axis, rdf_y_axis)
plt.show()
plt.clf()

irdf = rdf.InterRDF(CA_A_2, CA_B_2,
                    nbins=2000,
                    range=(0.0,100.0),
                    exclusion_block=(1,1),
                    )
irdf.run()

rdf_x_axis = irdf.results.bins
rdf_y_axis = irdf.results.rdf
plt.plot(rdf_x_axis, rdf_y_axis)
plt.show()

I do obtain some graphs, but these look nothing like an RDF.
Image of A to B

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can pass the "start" and "stop" keyword arguments to the analysis class's "run" method:
irdf.run(start=100, stop=1000)

Source:
https://docs.mdanalysis.org/stable/documentation_pages/analysis/base.html#MDAnalysis.analysis.base.AnalysisBase.run
